# Authentication issue DRF, Firebase, React

Tags: reactjs, django, firebase, authentication

I am developing a web app which is using Django-rest for the backend, react-admin for the frontend, and firebase for authentication. Currently, I am developing the user part and have faced an issue. I have not used firebase before and the docs provided in firebase are not very clear to me.

The problem that I am having is that when I try to log in from the frontend it gives me access and lets me inside the website for a second and then it kicks me giving a 401 unauthorized status error and on the screen, a message pops up saying that my session has expired. When I check the console, everything is synced up and reads all of my credentials, generates a uid but somehow it denies it.

Here is the code.

**This is the view from django**
[image]

**This is my react-admin setup**
[image]

Could someone experienced help with my issue or guide me somehow, please?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.